# Speed up without a serial fraction

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, performance-testing, parallelism-amdahl

I ran a set of experiments on a parallel package, say `superlu-dist`,  with different processor numbers e.g.: **`4, 16, 32, 64`**

I got the wall clock time for each experiment, say: **`53.17s, 32.65s, 24.30s, 16.03s`**

The formula of speedup is :

```
                  serial time
  Speedup = ----------------------
                parallel time
```

But there is no information about the serial fraction.

Can I simply take the reciprocal of the wall clock time?

Answer (score 1):

> *Can I simply take the reciprocal of the wall clock time ?*

### No,
true Speedup figures require comparing Apples to Apples :

This means, that an **original**, pure-**`[SERIAL]`** process-scheduling ought be compared with any other scenario, where parts may get modified, so as to use some sort of parallelism ( the parallel fraction may get re-organised, so as to run on **`N`** CPUs / computing-resources, whereas the serial fraction is left as was ).

This obviously means, that the original `[SERIAL]`-code was **extended** ( both in code ( `#pragma`-decorators, OpenCL-modifications, CUDA`-{ host_to_dev | dev_to_host }`-tooling etc.), and in time( to execute these added functionalities, that were not present in the original `[SERIAL]`-code, to benchmark against ), so as to add some new sections, where the ( possible `[PARALLEL]` ) other part of the processing will take place.

This comes at cost -- add-on overhead costs ( to setup and to terminate and to communicate data from `[SERIAL]`-part there, to the `[PARALLEL]`-part and back ) -- which all adds additional `[SERIAL]`-part workload ( and execution time + latency ).

For more details, feel free to [**read** section **Criticism** in article on re-formulated **Amdahl's Law.**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

[image]

The `[PARALLEL]`-portion seems interesting, yet the Speedup principal ceiling is in the `[SERIAL]`-portion duration **`( s = 1 - p )`** in the original,

[image]

but to which **add-on durations and added latency costs need to get added** as accumulated alongside the "organisation" of work from an original, pure-`[SERIAL]`, to the wished-to-have `[PARALLEL]`-code execution process scheduling, **if realistic evaluation is to be achieved**

---

> *run the test on a single processor and set that as the serial time, ...*,

as @VictorSong has proposed sounds easy, but benchmarks an incoherent system ( not the pure-`[SERIAL]` original) and **records a skewed yardstick** to compare against.

This is the reason, why fair methods ought be engineered. The pure-**`[SERIAL]` original** code-execution can be time-stamped, so as to show the real durations of unchanged-parts, but the add-on overhead times have to get incorporated into the add-on extensions of the serial part of the now parallelised tests.

The re-articulated Amdahl's Law of Diminishing Returns [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) this, altogether with impacts from add-on overheads and also from atomicity-of-processing, that will not allow further fictions of speedup growth, given more computing resources are added, but a parallel-fraction of the processing does not permit further split of task workloads, due to some form of its internal atomicity-of-processing, that cannot be further divided in spite of having free processors available.

The simplified of the two, re-formulated expressions stands like this :

```
               1
S =  __________________________; where s, ( 1 - s ), N were defined above
                ( 1 - s )            pSO:= [PAR]-Setup-Overhead     add-on
     s  + pSO + _________ + pTO      pTO:= [PAR]-Terminate-Overhead add-on
                    N
```

Some interactive GUI-tools for further visualisations of the add-on overhead-costs are [available for interactive parametric simulations **here** - just move the **`p`**-slider](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mo8qduwj93) towards the actual value of the **`( 1 - s )` ~ having a non-zero fraction of the very `[SERIAL]`-part of the original code** :

[image: live-GUI for interactive simulations]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say "serial fraction"? According to a Google search apparently superlu-dist is C, so I guess you could just use ctime or chrono and take the time the usual way, it works for me with both manual std::threads and omp.

I'd just run the test on a single processor and set that as the serial time, then do the test again with more processors (just like you said).

Comment: You mean running the code with a single processor. This is a solution but not efficient. I do not want to measure the serial time . Sometimes take a lot of time more than 300s

Comment: Then I guess you could do as you said yourself, time * wall clock reciprocal. Beware though, since performance doesn't scale linearly your results won't be absolutely accurate.